# Finding min in Binary tree?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to find the min for a binary tree, NOT binary search tree, but can't get the answer, code is below. Please tell me what is wrong. 
Edit: So with the help of a poster, I was able to get the code working. I made code 1 to work, but I don' understand why in code 2, we need to check for Math.min again when in code 1 we didn't have to do that.

Code 1:

```java
    static int min = 0;
    static public int findMinimumValue(Node root) {
       min = root.data;
           findMinimumValue(root, root.data);
           return min;
   }
      static public int findMinimumValue(Node root, int x) {

          if(root == null) {
                return min;
            } else {
                if(root.data < min) {

                    min = root.data;
                }
                int left = findMinimumValue(root.left, x);
                int right = findMinimumValue(root.right, x);
               return min;

            }
        }
```

Code 2:

```
   static public int findSecondMinimumValue(Node root) {
      // min = root.data;
        return findSecondMinimumValue(root, root.data);
 }
    static public int findSecondMinimumValue(Node root, int min) {

        if(root == null) {
              return min;
          } else {
              if(root.data < min) {

                  min = root.data;
              }
              int left = findSecondMinimumValue(root.left, min);
              int right = findSecondMinimumValue(root.right, min);


            return Math.min(left, right);
          }
      }
```

Comment: You never check if `root.val` is smaller.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I made the edit but it is still not working. could you please see why.

Comment: Return Math.min(min,Math.min(left,right)); you need to return min of 3. While calling the function init the min with Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1: Identify the problem

Follow through what all you have done in the code base. Let's make a binary tree:

```
      5
    /  \
   2    1
```

Clearly the minimum is 1, right? So, follow through your code with this example.

```
public int findMinimumValue(TreeNode root) {
    return findMinimumValue(root, root.val);
}
```

The root will be the starting point.

```
        int left = findMinimumValue(root.left, min);
        int right = findMinimumValue(root.right, min);
```

This is what each and every node will see (if it is not null). It's a recursive call to the left, then to the right after it has gone as left as it can.

#### finalMinimumValue(TreeNode(5), 5)

Calls the following:

```
int left = finalMinimumValue(TreeNode(2), 5);
int right = finalMinimumValue(TreeNode(1), 5)
```

#### finalMinimumValue(TreeNode(2), 5)

Calls the following:

```
int left = finalMinimumValue(null, 5);
int right = finalMinimumValue(null, 5)
```

#### finalMinimumValue(null, 5)

Does the following code:

```
return min;
```

What is **min**? min is, well, 5.

Does that make sense? We traversed over 2, yet still kept the min as 5.

## Step 2: Fix the problem

We concluded in step 1 that it makes no sense for us to not update min if we are currently at a node that is not the minimum. So, let's update it **before** we recursively go down also.

```
public int findMinimumValue(TreeNode root) {
    return findMinimumValue(root, root.val);
}

public int findMinimumValue(TreeNode root, int min) {

    if (root == null) {
        return min;
    } else {
        // update your min variable here by comparing it with the node you currently are at!

        int left = findMinimumValue(root.left, min);
        int right = findMinimumValue(root.right, min);
        if (left < min) {
            min = left;
        }
        if (right < min) {
            min = right;
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

## Step 3: Test the solution

Let's follow through with the same example. We are expecting it to say it is 1.

```
      5
    /  \
   2    1
```

#### 1: Compute left for the root node

Our Node's value is 5. Is 5 less than our Node's value (5)? No. So, don't update the min.

Next, call the left child, **Node(2)**

#### 2: Compute the min to return for Node 2

Our Node's value is 2. Is 5 less than our Node's value (2)? Yes! So, update our min value.

Now min is 2.

Next, call the left child, **null**. Since its left child is null, we return min, which is 2.

Now, call the right child, **null**. Since its right child is null, we return min, which is 2.

Well, left equals 2, right equals 2. So, return 2!

#### 3: Compute the min to return for Node 1

Our Node's value is 1. Is 5 less than our Node's value (1)? Yes! So update the min.

Now min is 1.

Next, call the left child, **null**. Since its left child is null, we return min, which is 1.

Now, call the right child, **null**. Since its right child is null, we return min, which is 1.

Well, left equals 1, right equals 1. So, return 1!

#### 4: Compute the min to return for the root node.

The left returned us 2.
The right returned us 1.

Since 1 is less than 2, 1 is the answer.

#### It works!

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you please read my edit? Also I'm trying to learn how to think recursively, do you have any suugesstions? (I can do simple recursion but with trees I get lost). Please suggest me something. I looked at so many tutorials and books but nothing is helping.

Comment: The best tip I have for recursion is think in first-person view. When you do for loops and while loops, you think in a wholistic perspective, like you are managing the entire world. But with recursion, you are thinking at an individual-level basis Get some practice by writing some for loops using recursion. Anything that can be written with a loop can be done recursively. Anything recursively can be done in a loop. @user11452926

Comment: Also, your second code should work. You might be not calling it correctly or something.

Comment: My second code is working. It's there for comparison. Do you remember using a particular source when learning recursion over Data structures?

Comment: Hi! I have another question called checkLeaves(). Can I chat with you about it?

Comment: I didn't use a particular source. It just took a while for me to wrap my head around. I'll check out your question soon. Also, if this question helped, do be sure to click the check mark button for the answer. (: @user11452926